# Forbidden Access after adding rewrite rule

Tags: apache

I have a simple webserver running on a remote machine which uses Apache/2.4.7, which serves content inside public_html folder. I initially had no custom configurations in `.htaccess` file. I have the files `index.html` and `offline.html` (and some other html files as well, but these two suffice to explain the problem I'm experiencing) inside the folder, which I can access without any problems when there are no Rewrite rules. When I add the following lines to the clean .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule . offline.html
```

The server starts giving a Forbidden Access error when I try to access the `index.html` file. It however shows no error and correctly serves `offline.html` when I try to access `offline.html`. I have tried searching for how to remedy this but haven't found a solution yet.

The loaded modules are:

```
core 
mod_so 
mod_watchdog http_core 
mod_log_config 
mod_logio 
mod_version 
mod_unixd 
mod_access_compat 
mod_actions 
mod_alias 
mod_auth_basic 
mod_authn_core 
mod_authn_file 
mod_authz_core 
mod_authz_host 
mod_authz_user 
mod_autoindex 
mod_deflate 
mod_dir 
mod_env 
mod_filter 
mod_headers 
mod_lbmethod_byrequests 
mod_mime prefork 
mod_negotiation 
mod_php7 
mod_proxy 
mod_proxy_ajp 
mod_proxy_balancer 
mod_proxy_connect 
mod_proxy_html 
mod_proxy_http 
mod_rewrite 
mod_setenvif 
mod_slotmem_shm 
mod_socache_shmcb 
mod_ssl 
mod_status 
mod_userdir
```

Comment: Can you show the config of your vhost? In my experience you sometimes need to set extra explicit configuration on your folder based on the mods that are active...